# AdMob setting is no working

Tags: android

I'm sure that my code is correct, because I can see the test `AdMob`.

But when I try to use the publish id on my `banner_ad_unit_id`, I can't see it. Why? Is it possible my admob request is so less?

My layout.xml setting:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

AdMob code setting:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(getActivity());
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));

    mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Also I add permission on my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tw.idv.morton.mydailysugar">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/medical_history512"
        android:label="@string/myAppName"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/medical_history512"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
        <!-- 2. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified|stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- 3. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

</manifest>
```

I add the id from my account:
[image]

It will show the request error:

```
06-27 17:20:42.819 1635-1635/tw.idv.morton.mydailysugar I/Ads: Starting ad request.
06-27 17:20:42.819 1635-1635/tw.idv.morton.mydailysugar I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("D4C3A767DB14E4027B1AD9084862CC62") to get test ads on this device.
06-27 17:20:43.308 1635-1661/tw.idv.morton.mydailysugar W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
06-27 17:20:43.310 1635-1635/tw.idv.morton.mydailysugar W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
06-27 17:20:43.311 1635-1635/tw.idv.morton.mydailysugar I/Ads: onAdFailedToLoad
```

I really don't know why the reason. I want to see the real ad, some one can tell me what step I miss it.